# How to execute update in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying execute update to object but it always throws an exception `illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open session`. I can make insert but update I can't.

How could I solve it ?

**DBConnect**

```
    public class DBConnect {

            private static ISessionFactory session;
            private const String HOST = "localhost";
            private const String USER = "root";
            private const String PASSWORD = "";
            private const String DB = "pubcontrol";

            /** create a connection with database */
            private static ISessionFactory createConnection() {

                if (session != null)
                    return session;

                //database configs
                FluentConfiguration _config = Fluently.Configure().Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
                                                                           x => x.Server(HOST).
                                                                              Username(USER).
                                                                              Password(PASSWORD).
                                                                              Database(DB)
                                                                            ))
                                                                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PerfilMap>())
                                                                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ModuloMap>())
                                                                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PermissaoMap>())
                                                                            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true));

                session = _config.BuildSessionFactory();
                return session;
            }


            /** open a session to make transactions */
            public static ISession openSession() {
                return createConnection().OpenSession();
            }
        }
```

**GenericDAO**

```
public class GenericDAO<T> : IPersist<T> where T : class {

        public void insert(T obj) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
            try {
                _session.Save(obj);
                _transaction.Commit();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                if (!_transaction.WasCommitted) {
                    _transaction.Rollback();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Erro tentando salvar: " + e.Message, "Aviso",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }


        public void update(T obj) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
            try {
                _session.Update(obj);
                _transaction.Commit();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                if (!_transaction.WasCommitted) {
                    _transaction.Rollback();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Erro tentando alterar: " + e.Message, "Aviso", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }



        public void delete(T obj) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
            try {
                _session.Delete(obj);
                _transaction.Commit();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                if (!_transaction.WasCommitted) {
                    _transaction.Rollback();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Erro tentando deletar: " + e.Message, "Aviso", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }



        public T findObject(long id) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            return _session.Load<T>(id);
        }


        public void saveOrUpdate(T obj) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
            try {
                _session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
                _transaction.Commit();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                if (!_transaction.WasCommitted) {
                    _transaction.Rollback();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Erro tentando salvar ou alterar: " + e.Message, "Aviso",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

**PermissaoDAO**

```
public class PermissaoDAO : GenericDAO<Permissao> {

        public IList<Permissao> findAll() {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            IList<Permissao> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Permissao p")                
                .List<Permissao>();
            return list;
        }


        /** verifica se o perfil ou o modulo estao adicionados */
        public Boolean isExistPerfilAndModulo(Permissao permissao) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            IList<Permissao> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Permissao p WHERE p.perfil = :p AND p.modulo = :m")
                .SetParameter("p", permissao.perfil)
                .SetParameter("m", permissao.modulo)
                .List<Permissao>();
            if (list.Count > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /** retorna a permissao */
        public Permissao getPermissao(Permissao permissao) {
            ISession _session = DBConnect.openSession();
            IList<Permissao> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Permissao p WHERE p.perfil = :p AND p.modulo = :m").SetMaxResults(1)
                .SetParameter("p", permissao.perfil)
                .SetParameter("m", permissao.modulo)
                .List<Permissao>();
            return list[0];
        }


    }
```

**Making Update**

```
/** insere Perfil + Modulo */
        private void insertPerfilModulo() {
            PermissaoDAO dao = new PermissaoDAO();
            Perfil perfil = (Perfil)cbxPerfilModulo.SelectedItem;
            IList<Modulo> lista = getListaModulo();

            foreach(Modulo m in lista){                
                Permissao permissao = new Permissao();
                permissao.perfil = perfil;
                permissao.modulo = m;

                Boolean exist = dao.isExistPerfilAndModulo(permissao);                
                if (exist) {
                    Permissao p = dao.getPermissao(permissao);
                    dao.update(p);
                }else {
                    dao.insert(permissao);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is a very bad transaction handling and design misconception. Transactions should span the whole business operation, otherwise they do not make any sense. To make use of lazy loading, the session must be available while properties are read. Considering all this, the session and transaction must not be opened per query. This code doesn't belong to the "DAO". Where do you close the sessions anyway? By the way: updates are done implicitly by NHibernate, you do not need to call anything. This only works if NH is used the way it is intended to be used.

Comment: Better avoid code blocks which generate wide horizontal scrolls. Try reformatting them. Personally it can cause me to skip the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use multiple sessions with the same object. You should not create a transaction for every single database operation, this way transaction do not make any sense. Have each a session and transaction span the whole business operation and don't forget to close (or dispose) both at the end.

Update is implicit for every object within the session. Every object that had been queried or inserted is managed by the session.

When using NHibernate, code usually looks like this (exemplary, can look very different depending on how you design your DAO, but the concept should be the same):

```
using (session = dao.CreateSession())
using (session.CreateTransaction())
{
  var myObject = dao.Get<MyObject>(id);
  if (myObject == null)
  {
    myObject = new MyObject();
    dao.Insert(myObject);
  }
  myObject.Property = 3;
  dao.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Do you looked  my code ? What do you suggest to change is it in `GenericDAO` or in `PermissaoDAO` ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva It looks like you need to learn how an ORM is supposed to be used. (Your current code flaws are not specific to NHibernate). For an MVC app, this [blog series](/a/5908834/1178314) give a starting point.